# How can I lock memory when creating a device in Directx9?

Tags: windows, locking, buffer, directx, msaa

I cannot use the D3DPRESENTFLAG_LOCKABLE_BACKBUFFER locking flag while enabling multisampling when creating the device in Directx9. What path should I follow instead? I would like to point out that I am a novice in these matters. That's why I would appreciate it if you could explain it with examples. And what problems might occur if I don't use this flag?